# Thread already started- trans data via bluetooth

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, bluetooth, onresume

This is my : bluetooth.java. When I test my app, its jumps out this errors "Thread are already started. Then I can't sent my data anymore, then i get out of my app, then I start my app again, then it allows my to use app. 
So confusing.
I hope you will help me.
Thank for your help .

```
public class bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity {

// SPP UUID service
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
// MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
private static String address ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);
    on = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_enable);
    find = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
    mPairedBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_view_paired);
    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mProgressDlg = new ProgressDialog(this);
    back =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backblue);
    ontext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connecttext);

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(bluetooth.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



    //xử lí các nút
    if (BA == null) {
        showUnsupported();
    } else {
        mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

                if (pairedDevices == null || pairedDevices.size() == 0) {
                    showToast("No Paired Devices Found");
                } else {
                    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

                    list.addAll(pairedDevices);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(bluetooth.this, DeviceListActivity.class);

                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", list);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                BA.startDiscovery();
            }
        });

        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (BA.isEnabled()) {
                    BA.disable();
                    showDisabled();
                   /* try
                    {
                        btSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2)
                    {

                    }*/
                    on.setImageResource(R.drawable.offlight);

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);

                    on.setImageResource(R.drawable.onlight);

                }
            }
        });

        if (BA.isEnabled()) {
            showEnabled();

        } else {
            showDisabled();
        }
    }

    //thong bao cho may la chuong trinh nay co he su dung dc gi bluetooth
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    /* BroadcastReceiver dùng để nhận các intent từ hệ thống hoặc trao đổi dữ liệu giữa hai hay nhiều ứng dụng.*/
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


    // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
    address = "30:14:10:09:07:86";

    //create device and set the MAC address
    BluetoothDevice device = BA.getRemoteDevice(address);

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
    //btSocket.connect();
    try
    {
        btSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try
        {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2)
        {
            //insert code to deal with this
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cant do this",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    ConnectedThread.createInstance(btSocket);


    //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
    //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
    if(ConnectedThread.getInstance()!= null){
        ConnectedThread.getInstance().start();
    }else {
        ConnectedThread.getInstance().cancel();
    }


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();



}

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}




private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                showToast("Enabled");

                showEnabled();
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

            mProgressDlg.show();
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            mProgressDlg.dismiss();

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(bluetooth.this, DeviceListActivity.class);

            newIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", mDeviceList);

            startActivity(newIntent);
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            mDeviceList.add(device);

            showToast("Found device " + device.getName());
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: What kind of bluetooth module are you trying to connect to ?

Comment: @A.Omar : hc 05 ( with aduino )

Answer (score 1):

This is a library I made, you may want to give it a shot:

[**https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Android**](https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Android)

It works perfectly with the HC-06, it should be the same for you. This is how I use the class:

```
Bluetooth bt = new Bluetooth();
bt.enableBluetooth();

bt.setBluetoothCallback(new Bluetooth.BluetoothCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        bt.send("hello world!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(BluetoothDevice device, String message) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Disconnected!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Received: "+message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: "+message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectError(BluetoothDevice device, String message) {
        Log.e(TAG, message);
        bt.connectToDevice(device); // try to connect again
    }
});

/*
    Connection...
    /!\ you must be paired with the device via the settings app /!\
*/
bt.connectToName("HC-06");   
//you can also connect with:   bt.connectToAddress(address) and bt.connectToDevice(device)
```

**EDIT:** on Arduino side you have to put a **\n** at the end each message. You can simply use yourSerial.println("message").

**EDIT2:** You can find my Arduino code here: **https://causeyourestuck.io/2015/12/14/communication-between-android-and-hc-06-module/**

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer comes late, but I want to mention (and link) a message-based Bluetooth library for Android that is very simple to use, with the hope it will be useful for someone:

**https://github.com/BasicAirData/BluetoothHelper**

It is an easy message-based Bluetooth wireless communication layer between an Android device (the client) and a Microcontroller (the server), that can be used with any Arduino based microcontroller and a Bluetooth interface like the cheap HC-05.
It is licensed under the GPL-3 terms.

**The setup is very simple:**

1. Add Bluetooth permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

2. Declare a new BluetoothHelper instance into the activity:

```
    BluetoothHelper mBluetoothHelper = new BluetoothHelper();
```

3. Setup a BluetoothHelperListener to receive the messages and the changes of the connection status:

```java
    mBluetoothHelper.setBluetoothHelperListener(new BluetoothHelper.BluetoothHelperListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBluetoothHelperMessageReceived(BluetoothHelper bluetoothhelper, final String message) {
            // Do something with the message received
            // runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //     @Override
            //     public void run() {
            //         // Update your UI
            //     }
            // });
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBluetoothHelperConnectionStateChanged(BluetoothHelper bluetoothhelper, boolean isConnected) {
            // Do something, depending on the new connection status
        }
    });
```

**The usage is even simpler:**

- Connect with a paired device:

```java
mBluetoothHelper.Connect(mBluetoothDevice);
// mBluetoothHelper.Connect("HC-05");    <-- use it as alternative
```

- Send a message:

```java
mBluetoothHelper.SendMessage("Hello World");
```

- Check the connection status:

```java
mBluetoothHelper.isConnected();
```

- Disconnect

```java
mBluetoothHelper.Disconnect();
```

On the GitHub page is present a lot of documentation, a basic example with Android and Arduino code, and a link to a simple but fully functional open source app that uses it to connect with an Arduino using an HC-05.